# Jmeter json path extractor - How can we take random values from all captured variable?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

In jmeter I am capturing the variable using Jmeter json path extractor. There are around 7-10 values it captures,How can i pass any random value from all captured values?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) (from `3.0` version onwards) which is built-in `post-processor` in `JMeter`. Syntax is similar to `JSON Path Extractor`, so you can reuse the `JSON Path Expression` which is configured.

Specify `Match Numbers` to `0` for `random value`.

From Docs:

> **Match Numbers**    If the JSON Path query leads to many results, you can choose which one(s) to extract as Variables:
>
> - 0 : means random (Default Value)
> - -1 means extract all results, they will be named as _N (where N goes from 1 to Number of results)
> - X : means extract the Xth result. If this Xth is greater than number of matches, then nothing is returned. Default value will be
>     used

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you have this JSON Response:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    }
  ],
  "city": "Castle Rock",
  "state": "Maine"
}
```

And you have JSON Path Extractor to get `firstName` with the expression: `$..firstName`. It results into the following JMeter Variables

```
firstName=["John","Anna","Peter"]
firstName_1=John
firstName_2=Anna
firstName_3=Peter
firstName_matchNr=3
```

You can now get a random variable using [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions combinations like:

```
${__V(firstName_${__Random(1,${firstName_matchNr},)})}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Combine Variables with Functions]

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more details on the approach.

Comment: I had to add a "-1" to the field "Match No." to get it working.